# Unable to pin application to taskbar (Solus)

Tags: desktop-environment, solus

I'm very new to Linux, and I'm trying to make my application (bash script) pinnable to taskbar (I have Solus).

I'm doing this via desktop entry (copied and modified from another application that is pinnable). This is my "install"-script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

BASE_DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)" || exit 2

mkdir -p "$HOME"/.local/share/applications

cat <<EOF > "$HOME"/.local/share/applications/example.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Example
Exec=$BASE_DIR/example.sh
Icon=$BASE_DIR/example.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Keywords=example;sample;test;
EOF
```

However, my application still cannot be pinned/favorited to taskbar. But it does appear in Solus application menu, and the keywords will find it from there too.

What might I be doing wrong? Do I need to do something more?

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the solution shortly afterwards.

I needed to add this row to my bash script:

```
StartupWMClass=foobar
```

Where foobar can be found out via `xprop WM_CLASS` command.

Now my app is pinnable.